# How to manage state for navbar with multiple dropdown items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have navbar with 2 dropdowns that are managed with state. My issue is that when i click on one because both dropdowns open and close at the same time.

How can i make sure only the dropdown clicked on is open ?

```
 const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
 const [show1, setShow1] = useState(false);
  
                        menuItems.map((item) => {
                     console.log(item.href, item.submenuItems)
                     return (
                     item.submenu === true  ? 
                     
                     <li key= {item.id }className="nav-item dropdown" 
                     ref={ref}>
                     <Link
                       key={item.id} 
                       href={item.href}
                       passHref
                       spy={true}
                       smooth={true}
                       offset={-70}
                       duration={500}
                       //className="nav-item"
                       >
                       <a
                         onClick={() => {
                            
                            setShow(!show)
                        
                         }}
                         className="nav-link rounded dropdown-toggle 
                         dropdown-toggle-split"
                         data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                         aria-expanded={show ? "true" : "false"}
                         id="navbarDropdown"
                         role="button"
                         >
                         {item.title}
                       </a>
                     </Link>
```

Comment: add the state to the code, need know how  the state is implemented

Comment: Hi @keyvanKh i am doing this right away

Comment: You would need to separate the state into another file along with its code and then map over that component in here. This way each component will have its own state and won't interfere with each other

Comment: thanks @innocent. can you show me how this should look like,please? check out the snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-kare-li02jf?file=/Navbar.js

Comment: @Leo I will add a general solution step to the question. Also, A couple of things first why are using <Link> if you are using <a> tag, this doesn't make sense ? Looking at your codesandbox example Its not properly formatted and hence not added properly I tried forking and trying over it but I am not sure this is how you intended to display or you were trying to implement my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, You would need to create a separate file to track the individual mapped item as currently, you are mapping all the items to the same useState hook. So, it will toggle for all since its being used by each item. As you can see from the above example code you provided inside the `<a>` tag

```
onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
```

Just create a new file such as MenuItem.js

---

### MenuItem.js

In this file you would need to add over the HTML code you are generating for the mapped data and also add the useState Hook to this file

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default HeaderItem = ({ item }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <li key={item.id} className="nav-item dropdown">
      <a
        onClick={() => {
          setShow(!show);
        }}
        className="nav-link rounded dropdown-toggle 
        dropdown-toggle-split"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded={show ? "true" : "false"}
        id="navbarDropdown"
        role="button"
      >
        {item.title} - {`${show}`}
      </a>
      {show && item.submenu
        ? item.submenuItems.map((subitem) => (
            <ul>
              <li>{subitem.id}</li>
            </ul>
          ))
        : ""}
    </li>
  );
};
```

---

### File where you are mapping the data probably

After that you would need to make your changes in your current file where you are mapping the data. I took the liberty to copy the data off of the sandbox link you shared and used it to go over items and when clicked it should display the inside submenu contents for that item.

```
// import "./styles.css";
import HeaderItem from "./HeaderItem";


export default function App() {
  const menuItems = [
    {
      id: "home",
      title: "home",
      href: "/",
      submenu: false,
      submenuItems: []
    },
    {
      id: "services",
      title: "services",
      href: "/#services",
      submenu: true,
      submenuItems: [
        {
          id: "conciergerie",
          title: "conciergerie",
          href: "/ourServices/conciergerie"
        },
        {
          id: "property management",
          title: "property management",
          href: "/ourServices/conciergerie"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "properties",
      title: "properties",
      href: "/#properties",
      submenu: true,
      submenuItems: [
        {
          id: "buy",
          title: "buy",
          href: "https://www.idealista.com"
        },
        {
          id: "rent",
          title: "rent",
          href: "https://www.idealista.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "about-us",
      title: "about us",
      href: "/#about-us",
      submenu: false,
      submenuItems: []
    },
    {
      id: "team",
      title: "team",
      href: "/#team",
      submenu: false,
      submenuItems: []
    },
    {
      id: "contact",
      title: "contact",
      href: "/#contact",
      submenu: false,
      submenuItems: []
    }
  ];

  const headerItems = menuItems.map((item) => {
    return item.submenu === true ? <HeaderItem item={item} /> : null;
  });

  return <div className="App">{headerItems}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add your state inside your map so that map has its own state. Make sure you delete it from the main component ;)

```
menuItems.map((item) => {
     console.log(item.href, item.submenuItems)
     const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
     return (
     ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to (and should not) set a state inside any loop.

You could just give one state to one dropdown and one state to the other.

```js
const [dropdownOpen1, setdropdownOpen1] = useState(false)
const [dropdownOpen2, setdropdownOpen2] = useState(false)
```

As mentioned above, you create two separate dropdown components, with each dropdown having its own state per component.

This way each dropdown has its own state, and you can't reuse that state for another dropdown.